# matlab style indexing of a C++ array

Tags: c++, matlab, indexing

I would like to know what the most efficient c++ implementation of the following matlab idiom is.

Suppose I have 3 vectors in matlab, x, y and idx.

```
x = [13,2,5.5,22,107]
y = [-3,100,200]
idx = [1,2,5]
```

I want to replace positions 1,2 and 5 of x with the contents of y. In matlab I do

```
x[idx] = y
```

What is the best way to do this in c++?

Comment: Using [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) is probably easiest.

Comment: What does "*most efficient*" mean? Does it mean "Easiest to code?" Or, "Most likely to yield a maintainable program?" "Fastest compilation time?"

Comment: that's a point well taken. tempted to say I mean the intersection of all three, but really it's 1. easiest to code, 2. most likely to yield.... actually I don't care about compilation time but about run time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) library probably comes closest as one of its goals is to make things easy for folks used to Matlab.

Here is a short example (and `uvec` is a typdef for vector of unsigned ints)

```
// set four specific elements of X to 1
uvec indices;
indices << 2 << 3 << 6 << 8;

X.elem(indices) = ones<vec>(4);
```

Obviously, the right-hand side could be any other vector of the same dimension as the index.

But there are few language-imposed constraints you cannot overcome:

- zero-based indexing at the C++ level (which you could alter, but few C / C++ programmers will consider it a good idea)
- certain operators, including `[`

Comment: Spot on. I had looked at RcppArmadillo but had not seen the .elem() member function. Thanks!

Comment: This indexing is actually new and post 3.0 Armadillo. And glad to know you actually meant RcppArmadillo rather than Matlab all along.  There is an Armadillo tag here at SO...

Comment: Ah, there you go. Excellent addition. yes i disguised as a matlab user because... actually I wonder why. Should have known better. Anyway, might see you soon under the Armadillo tag! thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

A loop seems simple enough, although it can be made simpler with a helper function.

```
// helper function to get the size of an array
template<typename T, size_t S>
constexpr size_t size(T (&)[S])
{
  return S;
}

// loop
for (size_t i = 0; i < size(idx); ++i) x[idx[i]] = y[i];
```

Of course, here you should check that `y` is large enough:

Comment: will this not set ALL indices though? he only wants to set them at the indices specified in `idx`

Comment: @mathematician1975 I had a typo in my first attempt.

Comment: I am glad you told me that!! I though I was going mad

Comment: @juanchopanza: Will that not lead to `i` being 1, 2, 5 in sequence? whereas we need 0, 1, 2 to iterate over `y`.

Comment: @Component10 it sets elements positions 1,2,5 in x to the values in positions 1,2,5 from y. I don't know if matlab starts from 1 or 0 though.

Comment: @Component10 that's what I thought as well. cannot try it out because I'm not on c++11.

Comment: @Component10 aha, I see. This answer is totally wrong. I will fix or delete. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Component10 OK, fixed. It isn't as concise as the first version, unfortunately.

Comment: @FlorianOswald I fixed this. The code is less concise, but the helper function if totally generic so can e used elsewhere (in fact I am surprised the C++ standard doesn't have it).

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in pretty basic C++ (with no prizes for elegance) try this:

```
double x[] = { 13.0, 2.0, 5.5, 22.0, 107.0 };
double y[] = { -3.0, 100.0, 200.0 };
size_t idx[] = { 1, 2, 5 };

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x)/sizeof(double); ++i )
    cout << x[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

// Make a mutable copy of x
double x1[ sizeof(x)/sizeof(double) ];
std::copy( x, x + sizeof(x)/sizeof(double), x1 );

// The transformation
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(idx)/sizeof(double); ++i )
    x1[idx[i]] = y[i];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x)/sizeof(double); ++i )
    cout << x1[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Note exactly pretty, but it does give the following:

```
13 2 5.5 22 107 

-3 100 5.5 22 200
```

(Note that I've assumed that the indexing starts from 1 rather than 0 in `idx`)

Comment: +1 for the effort! yeah I have something similar like that now, picking the indices out one by one.