# Efficient way to construct an array taking elements with given indexes from another array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, indices

Is it possible to create an array from two other arrays, one being the source array and the second one containing the indices of elements to be taken, in C++, using only one command, without cycles, for example, using STL or boost? For example, given

```
double X[10] = [10., 9., 8., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.];
```

and

```
int n[4] =  [0, 1, 3, 9];
```

I would want to have

```
double X[4] = [10., 9., 7., 1.]
```

as the result.
In MATLAB, I would simply write something like X(n).

Comment: You mean even without using conditional statement and a loop?

Comment: You might find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161768/matlab-style-indexing-of-a-c-array/12161814#comment16275428_12161814

Comment: I'm always puzzled by the use of the word 'efficient' in questions like these. There are many ways in which code can be efficient. Unfortunately most of the time I think the questioner means 'using as little code as possible' or 'won't embarrass me when I show it to my professor'.

Comment: The most obvious way with 1 cycle and 2 lines will be the most efficient too in this case. No idea where did you get your restrictions from though

Comment: I doubt you could initialize a free array like that, but it's conceivable that you could initialize a template class member array from a given array of indices, like `double arr { get_index<I>(src)... };`, where `int ...I` is a pack.

Comment: Okay, I agree that "efficient" and "short" may mean different things. I am interested in efficiency. So "without cycles" just meant my vision that a cycle might be implemented, in some efficient way, in the internals of some library. If a cycle is the most efficient way, then the question is over!

Comment: @G-s If you look at the internals of STL or boost you will see lots of cycles. They're not magic, just well written code. If you want to do something repeatedly some sort of cycle somewhere is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Using c++11-features you could do it like this:

```
  std::vector<double> vec;
  std::transform(std::begin(n), std::end(n), std::back_inserter(vec), [&](int idx)
  {
    return x[idx];
  });
```

Without c++11, it could look like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Get_Idx
{
  Get_Idx(T (&t)[N]) : m_t(t) { }

  T (&m_t)[N];

  T operator()(std::size_t i) const
  {
    return m_t[i];
  }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Get_Idx<T, N> get_idx(T (&t) [N])
{
  return Get_Idx<T, N>(t);
}

  std::vector<double> vec2;
  std::transform(n, n + 4, std::back_inserter(vec2), get_idx(x));
```

Besides, why are you using c-arrays instead of STL-containers?

Comment: There was a typo in the first message. It was supposed to be Y instead of X in the third line. Thus, the sizes of all arrays are fixed, so it doesn't seem to be much difference between using arrays and vectors, in my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use std-containers and C++11 (sorry, not tested):

```
std::transform(n.begin(), n.end(), std::back_inserter(Y), [&X](int i) { return X[i]});
X = std::move(Y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's something semi-related that only works statically:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, unsigned int ...I, typename U, unsigned int N>
std::array<T, sizeof...(I)> build_array(U const (&src)[N])
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(I)> { { static_cast<T>(src[I])... } };
}
```

Usage:

```
auto arr = build_array<int, 0, 1, 3, 9>(X);
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double X[10] = { 10., 9., 8., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1. };
    auto arr = build_array<int, 0, 1, 3, 9>(X);

    for (auto i : arr) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
}
```